# Display Y-m-d format for wrong date format input in php

Tags: php, laravel, date, strtotime

I have an excel sheet with dates in Y/m/d H:i:s format. But in case if a user accidentally typed  2019/29/10 16:20:10 (ie, Y/d/m H:i:s) format it should convert to Y-m-d H:i:s format as 2019-10-29 16:20:10.

I have used the following strotime but it converted the Y/d/m format to 1970-01-01

```
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($rows[$i][2]));
```

If by mistake month and date got swapped, can we save and display the same in Y-m-d format??

Comment: If they enter 2019/02/04 - how will you know if it's in the wrong format or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: If the user mistyped it you need to reject it. You can't guess what kind of typo the user made.

Comment: I would rather give the user an error message saying that they need to write the date in the correct format.

Comment: If you use laravel, you should use carbon instead of `strtotime()`

Comment: Yes you are right @Nigel.

Comment: As @MagnusEriksson suggested, I should better give an error message. Thank you all for the valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any date then default date will be 1970-01-01 so please use condition before if

```
if($rows[$i][2]){
 date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($rows[$i][2]));
}
```

Another way is using [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) in Laravel Blade Template

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($rows[$i][2])->format('Y-m-d h:i:s')}}
```